# Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool

Tags: iis-7

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WAS
Date:          13.06.2012 08:34:45
Event ID:      5002
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-QU022VN756J
Description:
Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
```

Please provide near solution for this problem. I will appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 33):

IIS comes with a feature called Rapid-Fail Protection. By default an App Pool is configured to become disabled if a worker in the pool crashes 5 times within a 5 minute span.

The thresholds of this setting are able to be modified by right clicking on the App Pool going to Advanced Settings and modifying the 'Rapid-Fail Protection' properties. However, this event indicates that there is likely a serious issue in your application that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 13):

I got tensed about this issue and finally i got solved.

Please make sure that the following option is correct in Advance Settings in Application pool.

Application Pools>Default Application Pool > Right click and select Advance Settings.

And then check whether the option "Enable 32 bit applications" has been set as "False". It should be False

I got solved by did the above change.

Comment: *"Enable 32 bit applications"* is set to false by default and apparently might produce AppPool crashes for some applications which cannot deal with that. Subsequent crashes would lead to deactivation of the entire pool through the *Rapid-Fail Protection* feature (which is also configurable through the advanced settings dialog of the pool)

Comment: i have same issue, my application is hosted in 64 bit server only. How the 32 bit applications deal with that?

Comment: THANK YOU  I would have never guessed this.

Comment: Sorry, need to clarify here - does setting "Enable 32 bit applications" to false, or true, solve the problem?

Comment: Updated the answer now. It should be False

Comment: _Enable 32 bit applications_ really means "run the w3wp.exe worker process in 32-bit mode". Depending on your code this might be good, bad, or irrelevant. If you're using dlls that need 64-bit then you'll want _Enable 32 bit applications_ = False (i.e. run as 64-bit). If you're using dlls that need 32-bit then you'll want _Enable 32 bit applications_ = True (i.e. run as 32-bit). If you don't have dependencies that care about 64-bit or 32-bit then you probably don't care about this setting. In all cases you should check other Event Log messages to see what the real cause of the failures is.

Answer (score 6):

I Got this error when i installed URL Rewrite Module, install correct URL Rewrite Module  to fix this.
To verify this error cause of URL Rewrite Module check events logs .

1. windows logs>> System>> Click on recent Error, In Error details 
       it will show "Application pool 'DefaultAppPool(or
       YourApplicationpool)' is being automatically disabled due to a
       series of failures in the process(es) serving that application
       pool."
2. Windows logs>> Application>> click on recent error,  In error
       details it will show  "The Module DLL
       'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll' failed to load. the data 
       is the error."

I hope this will help You.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to know the detail of the generic error. This helped me identifying it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's a registry permission issue.  This should help:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885654

You might also need to add read/write permissions for NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE (or NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM or the account used by your application pool) to c:\Windows\TEMP.
See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/176e9b6d-7b1b-4667-b55e-330bec133f37/

Comment: What register keys are needed? using Regmon tool it gives me about ~1000 keys saying: Desired Access. Not sure which one is needed