# IIS Application pool is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool

Tags: .net, iis, application-pool

An IIS app pool which is running only one application  seems to be failing enough times for the fail safe mechanism to kick in and disable the app pool.

Is there any way i can find a more detailed error to find out what could be the underlying cause? the Event viewer gives only a high level error message.

If it helps, the application is an asmx web service application.

Answer (score 0):

The serious issue of the application pool only can be checked by the Windows Event Log. We only can pinpoint the problem with experience. Try to post the error message and locate the issue by search it over the internet. Mostly of cases due to the instability of running the application in 64-bit mode.
Please refer to the below link.
[IIS7: A process serving application pool 'YYYYY' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204444/iis7-a-process-serving-application-pool-yyyyy-suffered-a-fatal-communication)
https://serverfault.com/questions/878094/error-with-iis-7-application-pool-has-been-automatically-disabled
[Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010807/application-pool-defaultapppool-is-being-automatically-disabled-due-to-a-serie)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.